# Crystal Report Viewer print/export buttons not working in ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, printing

My MVC app uses the push model and the CR viewer for reporting. All works great in displaying the report in the viewer however the print/export buttons give the javascript error 'Object not supported by this action'. I am using VS 2008 and MVC. This happens in my dev environment. Any ideas?

Comment: Hai mike, I think it may be due to your version of crystal reports with asp.net mvc ...

Comment: What version should it be? The about box in in VS says it Crystal reports for VS 2008. The verison in Solution Explorer for the dlls is 10.5.3700.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is so stupid its embarrassing - my popup blocker was causing this error. I did get another error or on th the deployed site however and that was a 404 not found on 'aspnet_client/System_Web/2_0_50727/CrystalReportWebFormViewer4/html/crystalexportdialog.htm'. I just created the folder and on the site and copied the contents of C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ASP.NETClientFiles\CrystalReportWebFormViewer4 to it and it fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was almost if not the same as yours. When I clicked export for print my report became clear. I updated my aspx page_load event to:

```
if (!isPostBack)
{
    Dataset allCompanies=datasetMethod(); ///Method Retaining a dataset
    ReportDocument oRpt=new ReportDocument();
    oRpt.SetDataSource(allCompanies);
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = oRpt;
    Session["Report"] = oRpt;
}
else
{
     CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Session["Report"];
}
```

Comment: With the Crystal Report Web Viewer, you have to store the Report Document in a Session and use that as the DataSource anytime the page is in Post Back. Without this, not only does your Print and Export buttons not work, but you will also have issues if you use Paging and basically anything that causes the Report Viewer to reload. Without this.. the "Current" report document is actually being refreshed from scratch and forgetting whatever caused the post back to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Crystal Report uses javascript files to print and its own images that should be included on root directory of the website. 
I have solved this issue by creating folers on root directory of my website

**aspnet_client/system_web/2_0_50727/**

and copied the folder **CrystalReportWebFormViewer4** from this path

**C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ASP.NETClientFiles\CrystalReportWebFormViewer4**

in **2_0_50727** folder i have created. Now print images and print/export buttons are displayed and also print and export functionality is working fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was also faced with the same problem when I deployed my Website on IIS. Crystal Report didn't show me the `print`, `next`, `previous` etc. buttons, I then just created a folder  inside `wwwroot` folder.

The complete path is:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\System_Web\2_0_50727`
```

I copied `CrystalReportWebFormViewer4` from

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ASP.NETClientFiles\CrystalReportWebFormViewer4

and pasted inside the `2_0_50727` folder.

Everything is now OK, but on the browser you have to allow the pop-up window to print your document.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem when i removed the `Default Web Site` from IIS and added a new Website with different location.

If you are doing so, then we need to copy the `aspnet_client` folder from location `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` to the location where the newly configured Web site is mapped.